# length of ticks in a tickless operating system

Tags: c#, .net

My understanding of winmm.dll is it can change the length of the "ticks".

In a tickless OS like Windows 7, what use/effect does this have if any?

Comment: Are you talking about timeBeginPeriod or timeSetEvent?  What does 'tickless' mean?

Comment: @Hans: Yes for timeBeginPeriod. WinXP used a hardware timer that caused a "tick". A tick was the smallest quantum of time between preempting threads. When a tick happened, it caused an interrupt that forced the current thread back into the kernel where the kernel could do thread scheduling. The finer the resolution a tick is, the more interrupts happen which reduced system performance but increased the fine-gainness of scheduling. Win7 instead uses a "tickless" interrupt that can be scheduled in millionths of a second. Instead of interrupting every X ms, the kernel says wake me up at this time

Comment: I think the bigger question is "what are you trying to do?"

Comment: @Jim: Nothing specific right now. More of a curiosity thing because I can't find consistent data on the web. I do a lot of internal tools and I'm in a hybrid Consultant/Architect/Programmer position. I find if I can only think like a hammer, then every problem is a nail; the more I know the better I can fix issues. A lot of my job is keeping up to date and I'm quite weak in the area of low latency processing. :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling [timeBeginPeriod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757624%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) doesn't let you change the length of "ticks", but rather sets the minimum resolution that you expect from the multimedia timer functions.  If you call `timeBeginPeriod(1)`, then you can expect 1-millisecond resolution (at best) from your timers you set by calling `timeSetEvent`.

Unless you're using the multimedia timers (which you probably shouldn't be doing, considering they've been deprecated in favor of the thread pool timers), there's no reason ever to call `timeBeginPeriod` or even to worry about it.  There are, however, compelling reasons *not* to call `timeBeginPeriod` or any other function that sets the minimum timer resolution.  See http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/pnppwr/powermgmt/Timer-Resolution.mspxas.

Windows keeps track of time in intervals of 100 nanosecond "ticks", regardless of what you set with `timeBeginPeriod`.  `timeBeginPeriod` is just a way to get a more granular periodic event if you really need it.  It has no effect on how Windows keeps time.

Comment: I don't have access to a machine with an OS prior to Win7, but all examples I can find on its use involve thread.sleep changing. To me this would mean the kernel tick has changed. Giving you +1 for tip on "pool timers".

Comment: I think this answer was good enough because it got me onto the track of TimerQueue's using the thread pool.